# Easily truncating a Double - swift

Tags: swift, truncate

I want to be able to take a longitude/latitude value of 19.3563443 and turn it into 19.35634 (five decimal places). Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NumberFormatter`:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let number = NumberFormatter()
}
```

---

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func fractionDigitsRounded(to digits: Int, roundingMode:  NumberFormatter.RoundingMode = .halfEven) -> String {
        Formatter.number.roundingMode = roundingMode
        Formatter.number.minimumFractionDigits = digits
        Formatter.number.maximumFractionDigits = digits
        return Formatter.number.string(for:  self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let value = 19.3563443
let roundedToFive = value.fractionDigitsRounded(to: 5) // "19.35634"
```

Answer (score 3):

Round, get double value back.

```
  NSString(format: "%.5f", myfloat).doubleValue
```

This won't truncate, but may be accurate enough for long/lat to 5 decimal places and is quick.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus - I think it's the best you're going to get out of a one-liner. For Lat/Long rounding to 5 decimal places shouldn't be an issue unless your finding a needle in a haystack (literally).

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus - Technically speaking, the case provided by the OP passes with my snippet. ^.^

Comment: 5th decimal place gives you the precision of ~1.1 meters. This solution will be off by an average of 0.55 meters.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different answer on a different site and wanted to share it:

```
   let x = 129.88888888777
   let y =  Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
```

`y returns 129.888`

thanks to swift's "round" function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a math problem, not a coding problem. Converting between `String` and `Double` is not very attractive. In mathematics, truncating digits to the right of the decimal is called reducing scale. To truncate a non-integer, all you need to do is move the decimal to the right however many places you want it truncated (multiply it by `10` to move it one, multiply it by `100` to move it two, etc.), convert it into an integer (which drops everything after the new decimal), and then divide it back by the original multiplier to return the decimal to its original position.

To reduce pi's scale to `3`:

1. move the decimal right: 3.1415927 * 10^3 = 3141.5927
2. zero the fraction = 3141.0
3. move the decimal back: 3141 / 10^3 = 3.141

Add it as an extension to `Double` for convenience:

```
extension Double {
    /// Reduces a double's scale (truncates digits right of the decimal).
    func reduceScale(to places: Int) -> Double {
        guard !self.isNaN,
              !self.isInfinite else {
            return 0 // if the double is not a number or infinite, this func will throw an exception error
        }
        let multiplier = pow(10, Double(places))
        let newDecimal = multiplier * self // move the decimal right
        let truncated = Double(Int(newDecimal)) // drop the fraction
        let originalDecimal = truncated / multiplier // move the decimal back
        return originalDecimal
    }
}

let dirty = 3.1415927
let clean = dirty.reduceScale(to: 2) // 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `NSDecimalNumber`. I don't know if this is actually better or worse than @Leonardo's answer. But when dealing with numbers I prefer to stick to numbers, and not convert to/from strings. The code below generates a function for a requested number of digits that can be reused as needed.

This truncates by rounding down. To get normal arithmetic rounding, change it to use `.RoundPlain` instead of `.RoundDown`.

```
func makeRounder(#digits: Int16) -> (Double) -> Double {
    class RoundHandler : NSObject, NSDecimalNumberBehaviors {
        var roundToDigits : Int16

        init(roundToDigits: Int16) {
            self.roundToDigits = roundToDigits
        }

        @objc func scale() -> Int16 {
            println("Digits: \(digits)")
            return roundToDigits
        }

        @objc func roundingMode() -> NSRoundingMode {
            return NSRoundingMode.RoundDown
        }

        @objc func exceptionDuringOperation(operation: Selector, error: NSCalculationError, leftOperand: NSDecimalNumber, rightOperand: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber? {
            return nil
        }
    }

    let roundHandler = RoundHandler(roundToDigits:digits)

    func roundDigits(original:Double) -> Double {
        let decimal = NSDecimalNumber(double: original)
        let rounded = decimal.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(roundHandler)
        return rounded.doubleValue
    }

    println("Digits: \(digits)")
    return roundDigits
}

let roundTo5 = makeRounder(digits:Int16(5))

roundTo5(19.3563443)
roundTo5(1.23456789)
```

Answer (score 0):

let x = (long*100000).rounded(.towardZero)/100000